# C++ FIR noise filter

Tags: c++, filtering, signal-processing

I'm digging up some info about filtering the noise out of my IQ data samples in C++.

I have learned  that this can be done by using a simple filter which calculates the average of last few data samples and applies it to the current sample.

Do you have any further experience with this kind of filtering or do you recommend using some existing FIR filtering library?

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific about the nature of your noise, and of your signal, and what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: My work is related to SDR radio. I'm capturing all types of radio signals (no matter the modulation) via my dongle using GNU radio software and saving them as binary files. 

Binary file, containing the IQ data samples, is than used as an input for my stand alone software which does the rest of the signal processing and should be able to filter the noise added to the signal during the transmittion.

Comment: It sounds like you need to get to grips with some of the underlying theory first, before you start trying to code anything. I suggest moving the question to http://dsp.stackexchange.com, since it's more appropriate for that site and you'll get better answers there.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I didn't know about this subdomain. Will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as "just get some library and it will do all the work for you"; digital filters is a quite complicated subject.

1. It is easy to apply digital filter to your data only if your measurements come at fixed time intervals (known as "sample rate" in digital filters). Otherwise (if time intervals vary), it is not trivial to apply digital filters (and I suspect you might need FFT to do it, but I might be wrong here).
2. Digital filters (both IIR and FIR) are interesting in that as soon as you know coefficients, you don't really need a library, it is easy to write it yourself (see, for example, first picture here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response : looks simple, right?); it is finding coefficients which is tricky.
3. As a prerequisite to find out coefficients, you need to understand quite a lot about filters: you need to know what kind of filter you need (if it is after demodulation - you'll likely need low-pass, otherwise see comment by MSalters below), you need to understand what "corner frequency" is, and you need to realize how to map those frequencies to your samples (for example, you can say that your samples are coming once per second - or at any other rate, but this choice will affect your desired "corner frequency"). As soon as you've got this understanding of "what you need in terms of digital filters" - finding coefficients is quite easy, you can do it either in MatLab, or using online calculator, look for "digital filter calculator" in Google.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation :) Well my sample rate on the receiver side is always fixed. But I will have to do a bit more reading about the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure that a lowpass filter is appropriate to filter noise from an FM signal, let alone more complex modulations. In any case, lowpass filters would only be appropriate **after** demodulation. Before that, you'd need a bandpass filter. And with any spread-spectrum technique that bandpass filter will need to be quite wide which means it still passes a lot of noise.

Comment: The application which I'm developing is not designed to demodulate the signals, it should be able to autodect the modulation type only. Basicaly it should be able to decide whenever the input signal is modulated with:
AM, FM, CW, SSB, QAM(QPSK etc), BPSK

Comment: @MSalters: yep, you're right. Will update the answer to make it clear,